# Non existing package

Tags: ros, rosserial, catkin-create-pkg, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Created a package of my own after installing the package rosserial,
   this went well. I've been following the [create a package tutorial.](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)
2. When listing the dependencies it claims that the package rosserial is missing as seen below.
3. What have I missed ?

---

```
   $
   $ catkin_create_pkg serial_test01 std_msgs rospy roscpp rosserial
   $
 Created file serial_test01/CMakeLists.txt
 Created file serial_test01/package.xml
 Created folder serial_test01/include/serial_test01
 Created folder serial_test01/src
 Successfully created files in ~/catkin_ws/serial_test01. Please adjust the values in package.xml.
   $
   $
   $ rospack depends1 serial_test01 
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'serial_test01' depends on non-existent package 'rosserial' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
   $
   $
```

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162696/non-existing-package/) by [ROSnewbie11](https://answers.ros.org/users/13246/rosnewbie11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-05-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROSnewbie11,

At this line:
`catkin_create_pkg serial_test01 std_msgs rospy roscpp rosserial`
You say that you want to create a new package `serial_test01` that depends on these packages `std_msgs rospy roscpp rosserial`. Appearantly rosserial cannot be found. That is either because it is not installed, or because ROS cannot find it.

To install do: `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosserial` if you are on ROS Hydro (or `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rosserial` for example. You can install it through apt-get, as it is an official package.

To make sure ROS finds it when it is installed, make sure to source both your installation as your workspace (make it part of your ~/.bashrc for convenience). So `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.

To test, you could do `roscd rosserial`: you should get to the folder containing the rosserial package. This otherwise would have failed.

The other solution is to remove rosserial from the packages dependencies (`catkin_create_pkg serial_test01 std_msgs rospy roscpp`). Do you need it? It is not in the tutorial you link to? Also, you can easily manually add dependencies at a later stage by adding them to the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files at the top level of your package.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) with karma: 432 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2